# How to separate my code into different methods

Tags: java

So I have an assignment where i'm supposed to create a program that generates 100 random integers and stores them in a single dimensional array. I am then supposed to calculate the average, standard deviation and variance. Through a lot of trial and error I was able to make a program that did this but what I missed was that it said to write a separate method for each property(average, standard deviation and variance). How would i go about doing that?

```
package homeassignment5;


public class HomeAssignment5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        n = 100;
     int[] random = new int [n];
     for (int i = 0; i<random.length; i++)
         random[i] = (int) (Math.random()* n);
         double total = 0;
         double average = 0;
         double variance = 0;
         double var = 0;
         double sd = 0;

         for (int element : random){
             total += element;
             average = total/n;
         }
         for (int i = 0; i<random.length; i++){
             variance += (random[i] - average) * (random[i] - average);
         }
             var = variance / random.length;
             sd = Math.sqrt(var);


    //System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
     System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
     System.out.println("Variance is " + var);
     System.out.println("Standard deviation is " + sd);

     /*for (int i = 0; i<random.length; i++)
         System.out.println(random[i]);
         */

    }


}
```

Might be a bit of a mess but i'm really new to java and this was the product of a ton of trial and error.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You want to know how to write a method?

Comment: I think you want to decrease the complexity of your main method. If it is then you should not put your whole programme into a single main method, main method should be clean and readable. You can divide your code into INPUT, OUTPUT and CALCULATION basically according to your programme.

Comment: is it a good idea to write a distinct method for variance and standard deviation? Both need the average... Sure, for learning, you may call the average calculation from within that methods... Anyway, my suggestion, write a method to create the random numbers, returning the array; one method to calculate the average, given an array of numbers; one method for variance, given the array, which calls the average; and the same for standard deviation. Example for **total**: `private static long total(int[] numbers) { long result = 0; for (int element : random) { total += element; } return result;}`

Comment: Yes. I looked at videos about making methods and calling them but there's a few things i'm confused about. Like if I split this into methods how would I be able to use the same array for all the methods. Also how do i share variables across different methods?

Comment: a video is probably not the best to learn programming... maybe I am to old, but I would suggest searching some written tutorials where you can learn at your speed... also, if this is an assignment, there should be some material to learn for it. In short, a method can receive arguments from the code that called it, like you are doing with `...println("Average...")` - here you are passing the String to the method. You want to pass `random` to a method defined like `private static long name(int[] numbers)` - where numbers will receive the passed value

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should help you.. 
All the functionalities are separated in form of methods, 
the initialization is separated.

** WELCOME TO REFACTORING **

```
public class Refactor {

    private int[] random;
    private int n;
    private double total = 0;
    private double average = 0;
    private double variance = 0;
    private double sd = 0;

    public Refactor(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.populateArray();
    }

    private void populateArray() {
        random = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++)
            random[i] = (int) (Math.random() * n);
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        average = 0;
        total = 0;
        for (int element : random) {
            total += element;
        }
        average = total / n;
        return average;
    }

    public double getVariance() {
        variance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            variance += (random[i] - average) * (random[i] - average);
        }
        variance = variance / random.length;
        return variance;
    }

    public double getSD() {
        this.getVariance();
        sd = 0;
        sd = Math.sqrt(variance);
        return sd;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Refactor ref = new Refactor(100);
        System.out.println("Average is: " + ref.getAverage());
        System.out.println("Variance is " + ref.getVariance());
        System.out.println("Standard deviation is " + ref.getSD());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the `average = total / n;` outside of the `for` loop in `public double getAverage()` since you're overwriting it with each itteration anyway

Comment: @T.Dirks makes sense, updated. Well anyways I was focussing on more of refactoring then optimization.. so... :)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for. Making methods actually really confuses me. Could you explain how you went from public Refactor to public double getAverage?. Specifically what is "this.n = n;". i'm assuming "this." is a function in java that i'll look at but what does it do here. Also does the array in "populatearray()" carry over to method "getAverage"?

Comment: @Toukenn I would request you to go through the basics of Java Programming first. The start can be SCJP bok by Kathy Seirra.  But to clarify on the question, you can research on the "this" keyword in java. Hope this helps. Remember, never give a fish, teach them how to fish.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several ways of going about this, but the easiest would probably be this:

```
public class HomeAssignment5 {
    private static int[] random;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        random = = new int[100];
        ...
    }

    public static void getAverage(){
    // void if you want to print it here, double if you want to print in main
        double average = 0;
        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
            total += random[i];

        average = total / n; // you'll want to do this outside of the loop to
                             // to get the correct result!
        System.out.println("Average: " + average);

    }

    ...
}
```

You could alternatively pass the array to each method as a parameter.
By the way, in what you posted here, you still haven't actually written any random numbers into the array, so remember to do that, it's currently still all zero.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I thought in this code I am giving the array 100 random numbers from 1-100.                                                                   
              int n;
        n = 100;
     int[] random = new int [n];
     for (int i = 0; i<random.length; i++)
         random[i] = (int) (Math.random()* n);                                                             How would i go about passing the array to each method?

Comment: My code should still work. You would initialize the array with random numbers in your main. But the alternative would be something like `private static void getAverage(int[] random){ ..}`, and then call it with `getAverage(random);` In this case, instead of making random available for the entire class, you would pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> How would i go about passing the array to each method?

The first and most straightforward of the three methods is `average`:

```
    static double average(int [] r)
    {   double total = 0;
        for (int e: r) total += e;
        return total/r.length;
    }
```

For the second method, the standard deviation, I recommend not to pass the array, but rather the variance, since if the program has calculated the variance anyway, it need not be recalculated, and if it doesn't have, the SD method can be called with a call to the variance method as its argument.

```
    static double SD(double variance) { return Math.sqrt(variance); }
```

For the third method, the variance, I recommend not only to pass the array, but also its average, with similar reasoning as above.

```
    static double variance(int [] r, double average)
    {   double var = 0;
        for (int e: r) var += (e - average) * (e - average);
        return var/r.length;
    }
```

With those three methods defined, you can now replace

```
         double total = 0;
         double average = 0;
         double variance = 0;
         double var = 0;
         double sd = 0;

         for (int element : random){
             total += element;
             average = total/n;
         }
         for (int i = 0; i<random.length; i++){
             variance += (random[i] - average) * (random[i] - average);
         }
             var = variance / random.length;
             sd = Math.sqrt(var);
```

with

```
     double average = average(random);
     double var = variance(random, average);
     double sd = SD(var);
```